# Transform a Collection of scalaz disjunctions into a single disjunction

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given the following method:

```
def foo(seq: Seq[Long]) : Seq[\/[String, Long]] = seq map { v =>
  for {
    bar <- returnsOptionLong1(v) \/> "first was None"
    baz <- returnsOptionLong2(bar) \/> "second was None"
  } yield baz  
}
```

I want to implement the following method:

```
def qux(initial: Seq[\/[String, Long]]) : \/[String, Seq[Long]] = {
  // ... Fill-in implementation here ...
}
```

In other words: how does one use scalaz to transform a sequence of disjunctions into a disjunction with the right-side being a sequence.

**Note:** If a cleaner implementation would involve making changes to `foo` as well (e.g. modifications involving changing `map` to `flatMap`), please include those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sequenceU` under `syntax.traverse._` to turn it "inside out." Alternatively use `traverseU` passing in `Long => String \/ Long` to do it in one pass.

Comment: ah yes.  I was originally using sequenceU, but alas, I was using it incorrectly.  Thanks Adelbert!